# Send request to gunicorn directly

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

We are running `haproxy --> nginx --> gunicorn --> django`. I need to send some request to django from the server itself, but can't use the http url i.e. either haproxy or nginx one due to some network restricton.

Can I send a http request to `gunicorn` directly using python. Like to the below url which `nginx` uses  `http://unix:/code/tanmay.garg/web/utrade/run/gunicorn.sock`

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do. "Sending a request to Django from the server itself" doesn't sound like something you should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can using the very flexible [NetCat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26781/29536) by giving it the path to the gunicorn socket:

```
nc -U /code/tanmay.garg/web/utrade/run/gunicorn.sock
```

Comment: this is not sending the request

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use django-signals, to trigger the task which you want to perform, you don't need to use external api call or any other.

You can read more about django signals from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) or [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)

Comment: actually gunicorn is not starting it's worker before any request is sent, so I am sending it the request to force start them .